# Mobile upload select camera

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, plupload

For our webapp we use the Plupload plugin for uploading files in the app. When using an input[type=file] field in our app: on Android and Ios the phone gives the opportunity to 
make an picture by the cam.

Plupload uses an a tag to click on when an user likes to upload an picture. But on Iphone
the user only has the ability to select an picture from the gallery when using Plupload. 
The Iphone does this because the file upload form is rendered by javasscipt in Plupload.

Is there an way to solve this?

**Normal situation:** iPhone gives possibility to make picture with build in camera

```
<input type="file" name="plaatje" placeholder="Maak foto">
```

**Plupload situation:** on Iphone only an photo of the gallery can be selected (a tag is generated by Plupload)

```
<a id="uploader_browse" class="plupload_button plupload_add" href="#" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">Foto's selecteren</a>
```

**Plupload settings**

```
$("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'html5',
    url : base_url+'genius/upload/image/',
    max_file_size : '3mb',
    unique_names : false,

    // Specify what files to browse for
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
    ],

    // Flash settings -> if needed
    flash_swf_url : '/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',

    // Silverlight settings -> if needed
    silverlight_xap_url : '/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Set multi_selection to "false"... this worked for me on my iPhone running iOS7